# Is there good way to support pop members from the Redis Sorted Set?

Tags: redis

Is there good way to support pop members from the Redis Sorted Set just like the api LPOP of the List ?

What I figured out for poping message from the Redis Sorted Set is using ZRANGE +ZREM  , however it is not thread security and need the distributed lock when multi threads accessing them at the same time from the different host.

Please kind suggesting if there is better way to pop the members from the Sorted Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do the job: wrap these two commands in a single Lua script. Redis ensures that the Lua script runs in an atomic way.

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local result = redis.call('ZRANGE', key, 0, 0)
local member = result[1]
if member then
    redis.call('ZREM', key, member)
    return member
else
    return nil
end
```

Comment: It support the concurrent multi threads operation from the different host servers?

Comment: @Jason Yes, of course. That's why I say it runs in an atomic way. See the doc for details :)

Comment: Unfortunately ,my application using the Java instead of the Lua.

Comment: The Lua script runs on the server side, NOT the client side. You really need to check the doc for how it works.

Comment: Thanks for_stack, I  would check it and response to you.

Answer (score 5):

In Redis 5.0 or above, you can use `[B]ZPOP{MIN|MAX}` *key* *[count]* for this scenario.

The `MIN` version takes the item(s) with the lowest scores; `MAX` takes the item(s) with the highest scores. *count* defaults to 1, and the `B` prefix blocks until the data is available.

- [`ZPOPMIN`](https://redis.io/commands/zpopmin)
- [`ZPOPMAX`](https://redis.io/commands/zpopmax)
- [`BZPOPMIN`](https://redis.io/commands/bzpopmin)
- [`BZPOPMAX`](https://redis.io/commands/bzpopmax)