# How to use zset in redis effectively for schedule task processing

Tags: redis, scheduled-tasks, zset

We have a use-case where we need to schedule **jobs** at different timestamps until it finishes successfully OR **max attempts** has reached.

We are thinking of using the `sorted sets` available in **redis** for this purpose.

On each new job we will put `node[data(string), timestamp_to_execute(double) as score]` into a zset (named 'delay-queue') in redis.

We will have few worker threads running in each instance of our application, which keep polling the top score job from the zset(delay-queue). If `[score <= currentime.millis()]` we will execute that job and remove it from the zset, else we wait for sometime and check again.

1. We don't want a job to execute twice, as we have multiple app instances running, how could we make sure the a job that's picked up by one app-instance should not be picked up by other as well for execution.
2. We are just evaluating on some edge cases: If we have some jobs to be executed in future on redis zset, but say redis goes down or data in zset gets refreshed or erased. The jobs would be lost, how do we make sure that should not happen. Would using redis zset a right choice in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to pick up a job from ZSET:

1. Check if the minimum score in ZSET is less than the current time.
2. If the check is successful, pop the minimum item in ZSET.

To prevent a job from being picked up by multiple apps, you have the following options:

- Use a Redis script to ensure these two steps run in an atomic way. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109614/775640
- Use WATCH to ensure these two steps run in an atomic way. See the Redis documentation: https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/ At the end of the document, there is an example on how to implement ZPOP with WATCH.
- Use [Distributed Locks with Redis](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/) to ensure that only one app is picking up the job at a time.

If you want to prevent data loss when Redis goes down, you can configure Redis to persist data on disk: https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/

Depending on how important your data is, if the data is extremely crucial (like transferring money between accounts), in my opinion, using Kafka is more suitable for such a case.

Update:

After reconsidering, Kafka might not be suitable for your case. You need an ordered set, but Kafka functions more like a message queue. You can stick with the Redis solution. If you require more data safety, using a database is also an option. You can save jobs in a table and use database transactions to ensure that only one app can pick up a job at a time.

Comment: Data is not crucial as such it's an SMS with a reference number that needs to be triggered on refund transaction success to the user.

Comment: We can put a job in the kafka, but to ensure the order of the jobs picked up by the workers. We have to keep consuming from the kafka and ignore the acknowledge step if the event score is more than current timestamp. And executing one job twice issue is also something we will face here when we have multiple consumers, For that indeed we might have to use the Redis again (distributed locking) correct?

Comment: After reconsidering, Kafka might not be suitable for your case. You need an ordered set, but Kafka functions more like a message queue. You can stick with the Redis solution. If you require more data safety, using a database is also an option. You can save jobs in a table and use database transactions to ensure that only one app can pick up a job at a time.